# Read icon with different sizes from exe and put it to glfwSetWindowIcon

Tags: windows, glfw

I saw a lot of questions related to this problem but I couldn't find a solution at the moment.

I have added an icon with different sizes to my executable using Visual Studio, and I want now to define the icon of the application by reading the app, in order to avoid to give the png with the exe.

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
// Defining the icon for the application
const size_t iconsNumber = 7;
GLFWimage icons[iconsNumber];

const std::vector<size_t> iconsSizes = {16, 20, 24, 32, 48, 64, 256};

// The icons are read from the exe ico
HICON    iconsHolder[iconsNumber] = { NULL };
ICONINFO iconInfo[iconsNumber];

HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);      // Points to the current executable
LPCWSTR iconAddress = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1); // Points to the icon .exe resource
for (size_t i = 0; i < iconsNumber; i++) {
    
    iconsHolder[i] = static_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(hInstance, iconAddress, IMAGE_ICON,
                                                  iconsSizes[i], iconsSizes[i], LR_DEFAULTCOLOR));

    GetIconInfo(iconsHolder[i], &iconInfo[i]);
    // From what I understood, the values of the pixels of each icon
    // are stored and may be accessed from iconInfo[i].hbmColor

    icons[i].height = iconsSizes[i];
    icons[i].width  = iconsSizes[i];
    
    // We should now read the values of the pixels that are inside the HICON
    //icons[i].pixels = pixels;
}

//glfwSetWindowIcon(window, iconsNumber, icons);
```

I know that my iconsHolder is never equal to NULL, but now everything that I tried failed. I don't know what to do now to move the data from `iconInfo[i].hbmColor` to `pixels`.